# Pattern replacement

Tags: shell, sed, scripting

Can anyone please explain to me in brief about the *syntax* of this command? I know the output of this command but want to learn how it is working.

I expect an explanation in terms of how actually this command is written and significance of each and every character used in the command.

```
sed -i 's|\(LAYOUT PATH \).*|\1 "../GDS/'$1'.gds"|g' drcCustimize2
```

Comment: First you have looked at the man page for sed and realize that this will edit the file (i.e. change and replace it with the edited contents).

Answer (score 4):

- `sed`: Call the `sed` command
- `-i`: Pass `sed` the -i option: Modify the file in-place
- `'s|\(LAYOUT PATH \).*|\1 "../GDS/'$1'.gds"|g'`: The '...'$1'..' are used to make this whole part one single argument to the `sed` command
- `s|\(LAYOUT PATH \).*|\1 "../GDS/'$1'.gds"|g`:

  - `s|pattern|replacement|options`: `s` is the substitute (or search and replace) command, the `|` characters are used to separate the parts of that command from each other
  - `\(LAYOUT PATH \)`: Search for the literal string "LAYOUT PATH ", and capture it into a group; the content of this group can be put into the replacement string using `\1`
  - `.*`: Match everything until the end of the line
  - `\1`: Put the matched group 1 into the replacement text
  - `"../GDS/`: Put the literal string `"../GDS/` into the replacement text
  - `$1`: Put the first argument to the shell-script into the replacement text
  - `.gds"`: Put the literal string `.gds"` into the replacement
  - `g`: Do the replacement for every match on a line; without the `g`, only the first match is replaced
  - `drcCustimize2`: The file that `sed` should change

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel for clear explanation                                                         Regards                                                              Madhvi

Comment: Strictly speaking `'s|\(LAYOUT PATH \).*|\1 "../GDS/'$1'.gds"|g'` doesn't necessarily make up one argument because `$1` is not quoted so the split+glob operator applies here. `'s|\(LAYOUT PATH \).*|\1 "../GDS/'"$1"'.gds"|g'` would be correct.

Comment: Also, the `g` is useless, as a pattern ending with `.*` cannot possibly match a line more than once.